# Does the linear span of norming extreme points contain all extreme points?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space, $X^*$ be its continuous dual space, and $B(X^*)$ be its closed unit ball, i.e., $B(X^*) = \{x^*\in X^*: \|x^*\|\leq 1\}$.

We say that $x^*$ is an *extreme point* of $B(X^*)$ if $x^*\in B(X^*)$ and for any $x^* = \frac{1}{2}(x_1^* + x_2^*)$ for some $x_1^*,x_2^*\in B(X)$, we have $x^* =x_1^*=x_2^*$.

We say that $x^*$ is a *norming* extreme point of $B(X)$ if $x^*$ is an extreme point of $B(X)$ that satisfies $x^*(x) = \|x\|$ for some $x\in X\setminus \{0\}$.

> Question: If $x^*$ is an extreme point of $B(X)$, then is it true that
> $$x^* = a_1x_1^* + \cdots +a_n x_n^*$$
> for some $n\geq 1$, $a_1,...,a_n\in \mathbb{R}$ and $x_1^*,...,x_n^*$ are norming extreme points of $B(X^*)$?